# RealmのXcode 7.1の対応状況について

Tags: swift, realm

下記の1行でコンパイルできません。

```
import RealmSwift
```

使用しているrealmのVerは0.96.1だと思います。
まだiOS9.1に対応できていないのか、私の設定が悪いのか？

ただ、開発環境をXCODE7.1にし、Realmのフレームワークを最新に置き換えただけです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'RealmSwift' and try again: /Volumes/Untitled/TypeArray/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

おそらく上記のようなエラーが出ていると思います。Swiftのコンパイラは少しでも古いバージョンでビルドされたモジュールを使えないので、Xcode 7.1でビルドされたフレームワークが必要になります。
Xcode 7.1でビルドされたフレームワークはまもなくリリースされますが、それまで待つか、CocoaPodsなどを利用してインストールしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。1日、CocoaPodsを使うか悩んだのですが、その知識が今は十分ではありません。
学習するのが早いか、新ビルドの登場が早いか・・・是非新ビルドの登場前にCocoaPodsを理解したいと思っています。

Comment: Xcode 7.1でビルドしたバージョンは今夜にでもリリースされる予定です。

Comment: 負けました・・・CocoaPodsは今後の学習の課題にします。

Comment: 後はソースコードからビルドしてもいいです。リポジトリをクローンして、`sh build.sh build`とするだけです。

Comment: Xcode 7.1でビルドされたバージョン 0.96.2 がリリースされました。Webサイト https://realm.io/ からダウンロードできます。

Comment: 有難うございます。今のところcocoapodsを利用してます。

Answer (score 2):

私も同じ状況に遭遇しましたが、CocoaPods、インストールで解決しました。今後は、Xcodeのバージョンアップデートを考慮すると、CocoaPodsでインストールした方が良さそうですね。

Comment: そうですね、今後のことを考えると、CocoaPodsを学習しておいたほうがよさそうですね。ありがとうございます。